# How to update column with another column in the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this :

```
+--+----------+--------+------+
|Id|class_name|class_id|medals|
+--+----------+--------+------+
|1 |7IPA1     |7       |3     |
|2 |7IPA2     |7       |2     |
|3 |7IPA3     |7       |5     |
|4 |8IPA1     |8       |1     |
|5 |8IPA2     |8       |7     |
|6 |8IPA3     |8       |3     |
+--+----------+--------+------+
```

I want data on `class_id` be 7IPA & 8IPA (4 first character from class_name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function:

```
 UPDATE MYTABLE SET CLASS_ID=SUBSTRING(CLASS_NAME,1,4)
```

Comment: THANK YOU, thank you very much @apome, maybe next time i wanna ask much question again :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using `LEFT` string function

```
Select LEFT(CLASS_NAME,4) from yourtable
```

Looks like you want a new column and not to update existing column, I will suggest you to create a computed column

```
alter table yourtable add new_class_id as (left(class_name,4)) persisted
```